# Without Ignoring NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium

By running below code, even without wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class), webdriver waits and ignoring NoSuchElementException. Then what is the use case of ignoring(Exception)? And Why ignoring NoSuchElementException not working?

```
dr.get("https://www.bankofamerica.com/");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dr, 30);
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.id("navCreditCard")))).click();
```

Comment: importing java.util.NoSuchElementException, instead of import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException?

Comment: I imported import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException; @ShehanWisumperuma

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: after 30 secs-NoSuchElementException@GregBurghardt

Comment: WebDriverWait already ignores this exception....  do you see timeout too?  It ignores it so that it can wait a certain amount of time while polling the DOM for the expected condition.

Comment: @pcalkins my question is- even without ignoring NoSuchElementException code, wait is ignoring NoSuchElementException.

Comment: WebDriverWait ignores NoSuchElement... it extends FluentWait.  ( https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it. By Default WebDriverWait ignores NoSuchElementException which is instance of NotFoundException class. from documentation,

> Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered
>   (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately
>   propagate all others.  You can add more to the ignore list by calling
>   ignoring(exceptions to add).